# How to Unhide UIView with animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, xcode8

I am trying to unhide **UIView** with animation, but it does not work for the iphone simulator 5. The view appears fine after unhiding on all other simulators except than the 5 and 5s.

What could be the reason. Unable to detect the problem. Any Help?

```
 /*To unhide*/
    self.view4.hidden=NO;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.view4.frame =  CGRectMake(2, 70, 70, 300);
        self.view4.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
    
    //for showing view3
    self.view3.hidden=NO;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [self.view3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 303, 320, 95)];
        self.view3.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
```

on button click the view3 does not appear :(. view4 appears fine. I have also tried by changing the frame values but no progress. On hiding and reducing the alpha for disappearing the view3 appears animating on the screen, but not on showing it.

[iPhone6splus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlVM4.jpg)

[iPhone5 Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7e9M.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the hard set coordinates you are using.  If you inspect the self.view.bounds (or the self.view3.superview.bounds) you will notice that the view doesn't have the same dimension on the iPhone 5 has it does on the iPhone 6/7 or the iPhone 6Plus/7Plus.  You should calculate the view position relative to the self.view.bounds metrics.

```
// for showing view 3
self.view3.hidden=NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    CGRect parentBounds = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect destinationFrame = CGRectMake(0,parentBounds.size.width,parentBounds.size.height-95,95);
    [self.view3 setFrame:destinationFrame];
    self.view3.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

The view should now always appear within the parent view bounds and be visible on the iPhone 5.

Comment: @ShahiJabeen Could I have a bit more background as to whether this code runs in a UIViewController implementation or inside the UIView and the relation to "self' ?  How are you creating view3 and how is it different than view4 ?  Is view4 a child of view3 or vice-versa?

Comment: "Its not working" is one of the least helpful things you can say on SO. Describe, in detail, what it is actually doing, describe how your views are set up and installed on-screen, the state they are in to begin with, and show full code, not fragments. You say "On hiding and reducing the alpha for disappearing the view3 appears animating on the screen, but not on showing it", which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @ekscrypto view3 and view4 are subviews of the main UIView, view3 and view4 don't have parent child relationship. i have added view3 and view4 by drag drop in the main UIView but i am setting their frames for each device. i have shown in the code. This code works fine for other simulators except iPhone simulator 5,5s.

Comment: @DuncanC As i suffered only with this fragment of code, so i shared it with you guys. I am working on photoEditor app, view3 shows the colour buttons and view4 shows different font buttons. the problem is only with view3. it does not appear on the screen when i click the add text button for adding the text and changing the colour and font of the text. view4 works fine. this problem appears just for iPhone Simulator 5 and 5s. I hope now you get my point.

Comment: check the images link that i have added for your understanding. Hope u'll understand my problem now.

Comment: @S_J Thank you for sharing the screens for your app.  I believe I now understand the issue and you will be happy to hear that all your animations are behaving exactly like you programmed them, no dark magic at play.

Comment: Then why view3 does not appear after the animation? while for the other screens everything is working fine

Comment: let me tell you one thing more, that view3 appears for all screens by using xcode 7.3 beta. but not for xcode 8.3.3. what could be the reasons. I am unable to find the solution

Comment: @S_J I recommend you read this page: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/you-probably-dont-understand-frames-and-bounds/

Comment: @S_J Another good read related to your issue: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html